# Where is the action is pointing to in Laravel form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.5

PS: I am new to Laravel. And following [this tutorial to create sample project](https://appdividend.com/2017/08/20/laravel-5-5-tutorial-example/?)

Everything is working fine. 
But I am not able to figure out how data is inserted into the database.

here is the form code

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('products')}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="price">Price:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left:38px">Add Product</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Here at the onsubmit action it is calling "{{url('products')}}" . 
What is the mean of this? Can anybody help?

If you need any other code let me know.

web.php

```
<?php

Route::resource('products','ProductController');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //

         $products = Product::all()->toArray();
        return view('products.index', compact('products'));

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
                                return view('products.create');

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //


        $product = $this->validate(request(), [
          'name' => 'required',
          'price' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        Product::create($product);

        return back()->with('success', 'Product has been added');;
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{url('/products')}}` means `url()` function will return base url and whatever added inside that method will append to base ur;

for example my website url is `https://stackoverflow.com/` then above method will return

```
https://stackoverflow.com/products
```

in your route you have to define

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

Laravel route  will point to your controller and method and in method you have a logic to insert into database

for better understanding

**url()**

The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path:
Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url

Also to learn more about route resource you can refer

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: there is no url() function in the php file

Comment: Ok Got it. But have one more query, now it is calling the store(Request $request) function of ProductController. How it is making decision which function is calling upon submit. since I have defined the only url('products'). So It means it will redirect toward productController. I have added the web.php and ProductController.php in question also.

Comment: laravel resouce predefined methods names like create ,store ,show.store for inserting and show for showing records

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is [Generating Urls](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#the-basics) This means it uses your app base url with the other urls you have in the string argument. Therefore, `url('products')` is the same thing as `http://yourwebsite.com/products` as the action on your form i.e where the form will be submitted to.

The other counterpart is [Urls for named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-named-routes) I will add a caption here in case the document link breaks at any point:

[image]

You see. This means that in your one of your routes has that name which you use to generate a url.

Since some of these helper functions are new to *you* (supposing you are learning by following a tutorial), my recommendation is to open [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5) and see how things are by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Route::ressource called 'product' and redirecting to ProductController.